# How to check content type using curl in shell

Tags: bash, shell, http, curl

I want to check content type of a file in a server.
Following code always echoes "image size is invalid".

```
    TYPE=$(curl -sI $IMAGE_LINK | grep Content-Type)
    IFS=" "
    set $TYPE
    echo $2

    if [ $2 == "image/gif" ] 
    then
        echo "image size is valid"
        exit 0  
    else
        echo "image size is invalid"
        exit 1
    fi
```

This is the output. Why comparison does not work when $2 is "image/gif"?

```
image/gif
image size is invalid
```

Additionally,
This is my unwanted solution.

```
    TYPE=$(curl -sI $IMAGE_LINK | grep "Content-Type: image/gif")
    echo $TYPE

    if [ ! "$TYPE" = "" ]
```

Comment: Use `grep` in PCRE mode (on GNU `grep`) as `.. | grep -Po '(?<=Content-Type: )[^;]*'`. Don't manipulate `IFS` without taking a backup of it _and_ the value is a single-whitespace by default.

Answer (score 7):

Extracting the `Content-Type:` header can be done with just curl and the [-w option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-w), like in this shell script:

```
type=$(curl -sI "$IMAGE_LINK" -o/dev/null -w '%{content_type}\n')

if [ "$type" = "image/gif" ]
then
    echo "image type is valid"
    exit 0  
else
    echo "image type is invalid"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `grep` and `IFS`, `set` etc, you can use a single `awk` to extract `Content-Type` header:

```
type=$(curl -sI "$IMAGE_LINK" | awk -F ': ' '$1 == "Content-Type" { print $2 }')

if [[ $type == *"image/gif"* ]] 
then
    echo "image size is valid"
    exit 0  
else
    echo "image size is invalid"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It can be done without awk too (the header field name check must be case insensitive): `type=$(curl -sI "$IMAGE_LINK" -w '%{content_type}\n' -o /dev/null)`

Comment: Excellent @DanielStenberg, you may add that as answer.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Didn't know curl had that option!  Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

The comparison doesn't work because there is a trailing carriage return at the end of `$2`.  You can see it if you do this:

```
TYPE=$(curl -sI $IMAGE_LINK | grep Content-Type)
IFS=" "
set $TYPE
echo -n "$2" | od -t c
```

Which will yield:

```
0000000    i   m   a   g   e   /   g   i   f  \r
0000012
```

Also, setting IFS isn't really helping you here since space is included in the default IFS setting.  You could set IFS to include the carriage return (`IFS=$' \r'`), or use another way to parse out the bit you need:

```
TYPE=$(curl -sI "$IMAGE_LINK" | grep Content-Type | tr -d '\r' | cut -f 2 -d ' ')
if [ "$TYPE" = "image/gif" ]
then
    echo 'It works!'
fi
```

Or, even better (as suggested by @DanielStenberg):

```
TYPE=$(curl -sI "$IMAGE_LINK" -w '%{content_type}' -o /dev/null)
if [ "$TYPE" = "image/gif" ]
then
    echo 'It works!'
fi
```